# Firebase / typescript issue - When I use this.ref.getAuth().password.email it works but I get FirebaseAuthData type error

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular

Firebase / typescript issue.

When I use this.ref.getAuth().password.email it works but I get FirebaseAuthData type error when I run typescript compiler?

Do I need to update my typescript version?

I'm using typescript version 1.7.3
https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js

Or maybe my version of firebase which is currently at: 2.3.2?

**This is the error I get in the typescript compiler:**

[image]

Comment: Would this work: getProviderData().get("email") ???

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, I just want to get logged in persons email. This person will be using the built in firebase authentication

Comment: Are you sure that this field should exist? Are you using definitions at all? It doesn't exist in these definitions - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/firebase/firebase.d.ts#L315 .

Comment: This is my current attempt: var email: string = this.ref.getProviderData().get("email");

Comment: do you know how to get the email from auth object once a user has logged in using firebase authentication?

Comment: This is what works but typescript compiler complains: 

  var authData = this.ref.getAuth();
     var email = authData.password.email;

Comment: Yeh i noticed its not in that definition. But its their in the repsonse for get Auth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FirebaseAuthData Interface doesn't contain any password attribute after seeing the docs posted by  Kamen Minkov.

after reviewing your code snippet , you can rewrite it as

```
var authData:FirebaseAuthData = this.ref.getAuth(); 
var email = authData['password']['email'];
```

this will probably not throw any ts compiler errors

Comment: Hi Nabeel, thank you I will test this tonight and let you know.